# How to do the complicated replacement using regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I encountered a deeply nested curly braces string, like this:

```
{{{text1},{text2}},{{text3},{text4}}}
```

I just want to keep the inner most curly braces and replace another curly braces with square brakets, so the result will looks like this:

```
[[{text1},{text2}],[{text3},{text4}]]
```

how to do this replacement with Regex.Replace() function in C#?
thanks

Comment: You should be able to achieve this using two replacements. One replacement based on a pattern matching a single `{` that is directly followed by another `{`. The other replacement based on a pattern matching a single `}` that is directly preceded by another `}` (look-ahead and look-behind zero-length assertion operators will help)

Comment: @elgonzo The depth of the nest is not fixed

Comment: `{(?![[:alnum:]])` and `(?<![[:alnum:]])}`

Comment: @TwenteMaster, nothing of my comment was about depth...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will take two replacement, first replace every `{` with `[` which is followed by `{` and second replace every `}` with `]` which is preceded by a non-word boundary `\B`. Try this C# code,

```
string input = "{{{text1},{text2}},{{text3},{text4}}}";
Regex regex = new Regex("{(?={)");
string result = regex.Replace(input, "[");
regex = new Regex("\\B}");
result = regex.Replace(result, "]");
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
```

Prints,

```
Result: [[{text1},{text2}],[{text3},{text4}]]
```

**[Online C# demo](https://rextester.com/NSA99968)**

You can even use a positive look behind `(?<=})}` instead of `\\B}` for second replacement but I deliberately avoided it to keep the solution simple and to make it work even for languages that don't support look behinds but using `(?<=})}` will be strictly better than `\\B}`. Choose as you like.

Comment: what if I also want the outer most curly braces don't change, how to modify the regex

Comment: @TwenteMaster: In that case you will have to replace only `{` that are preceded as well as followed by `{` so only middle ones get replaced. Same strategy for `}` brackets. Do you want me to update my post with a solution to that? I can happily do that too.